# Weird Behavior With Heaps and Negative Numbers

Tags: python, data-structures

I have an algorithm that creates two heaps, minHeap and maxHeap. The only difference between the two is that maxHeap reverses the sign of minHeap, a simple hack to use Python's heapq data structure as a max heap. Here's my code for creating the heaps (the heap key is basically the number of workers in a dictionary for a given day of the week):

```
for day in self.weekDict:
    if day != 'Saturday' and len(self.weekDict[day]) != 0: #saturdays and holidays not part of optimization
        heapq.heappush(minHeap, (len(self.weekDict[day]), day))
        heapq.heappush(maxHeap, (-len(self.weekDict[day]), day))
```

The minHeap works just as expected, but the max heap gives me odd behavior when there are more than one of the same key. See below:

```
[(-8, 'Thursday'), (-7, 'Monday'), (-5, 'Friday'), (-7, 'Wednesday'), (-7, 'Tuesday')]
```

Why are the last two days out of order? Is it because only the first day is guaranteed to be the minimum, and once I pop the first day off the heap will automatically adjust itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A heap is not a sorted list.  A heap is a binary tree which *happens to be stored* as a list.  The elements of a heap have the following property:

a[k] <= a[2*k+1] and a[k] <= a[2*k+2] for all k in a

See the docs for a fuller explanation and a nice picture to help follow the structure: http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#theory

Answer (score 1):

Heaps are not sorted lists.  They are lists from which you can quickly pull the first element, and also maintain the structure so that you can continue to quickly pull the next first element.  When you look at the heap as a list, the elements will not be fully sorted.