# heappush behavior in python

Tags: python, heap, heapq

I have an array **arr = [1,2,1,3]**.

When I use **heappush** function to push the array elements as they are into a heap, the order of stays exactly the same as it is in the array:

```
arr = [1,2,1,3]
heap = []
for i in range(len(arr)):
    heapq.heappush(heap, arr[i])
print(heap)

Result: [1, 2, 1, 3]
```

Now, if I push the **negative** values of the elements of **arr**, the heap becomes **sorted** as it suppoed to be.

```
arr = [1,2,1,3]
heap = []
for i in range(len(arr)):
     heapq.heappush(heap,  - arr[i])    <---- Here
print(heap)

Result: [-3, -2, -1, -1]
```

I want to know why **heappush** sorts the array elements when their negative values are added to the heap but it does not do anything when the positive values are pushed into the heap.

Comment: Have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/a/14282603/914874 answer?

Comment: The contents of a heap are not supposed to be sorted. That's why there's a separate term "heap" instead of just calling them "sorted lists".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known as the `heap invariant` and you can see this stated in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/heapq.html) as well where it says:

Heaps are binary trees for which every parent node has a value less than or equal to any of its children. This implementation uses arrays for which `heap[k] <= heap[2*k+1]` and `heap[k] <= heap[2*k+2]` for all k, counting elements from zero. For the sake of comparison, non-existing elements are considered to be infinite. The interesting property of a heap is that its *smallest element is always the root, heap[0]*.

Take note of where it says that the smallest element is always the root, `heap[0]`, which is evident by looking at your data. Also take note how both of your lists observe the properties listed `heap[k] <= heap[2*k+1]` and `heap[k] <= heap[2*k+2]` for all k.

Now if we take a look at your lists we can see the properties are observed:

```
inf = float('inf')
arr = [1, 2, 1, 3]

for i in range(len(arr)):
    x = arr[i]
    try:
        y = arr[2 * i + 1]
    except IndexError:
        y = inf
    print('x <= y is {}'.format(x <= y))

x <= y is True
x <= y is True
x <= y is True
x <= y is True
```

The same applies if you use the negative array. Hope that helps clear things up for you.

Comment: Note that it doesn't *have* to be a binary tree, either. You could use a higher-degree tree, at the cost of making the implementation more complex. The benefit would be better cache locality.